# Unable to mount btrfs becuase of because of unmatched "fsid"

Tags: hard-drive, administrator, hard-drive-recovery, btrfs, uuid

I ran `btrfstune -u /dev/sdc` and it failed, now I am not able to mount this disk.

Errors in `dmesg` are

```
[   46.388877] BTRFS error (device sdc): dev_item UUID does not match metadata fsid: 35f9709d-b959-4b3a-9abf-28874cdaee9e != 1b8c28ca-bf77-46ce-b793-f56a03691c96
[   46.388934] BTRFS error (device sdc): superblock contains fatal errors
[   46.389296] BTRFS error (device sdc): open_ctree failed
```

`btrfs inspect-internal dump-super /dev/sdc` gives

```
superblock: bytenr=65536, device=/dev/sdc
---------------------------------------------------------
csum_type       0 (crc32c)
csum_size       4
csum            0x5b07cc16 [match]
bytenr          65536
flags           0x800000001
            ( WRITTEN |
              CHANGING_FSID )
magic           _BHRfS_M [match]
fsid            35f9709d-b959-4b3a-9abf-28874cdaee9e
metadata_uuid       35f9709d-b959-4b3a-9abf-28874cdaee9e
label           
generation      20919
root            923791523840
sys_array_size      129
chunk_root_generation   19860
root_level      1
chunk_root      919925211136
chunk_root_level    1
log_root        0
log_root_transid    0
log_root_level      0
total_bytes     4000797868032
bytes_used      1333174341632
sectorsize      4096
nodesize        16384
leafsize (deprecated)   16384
stripesize      4096
root_dir        6
num_devices     2
compat_flags        0x0
compat_ro_flags     0x0
incompat_flags      0x171
            ( MIXED_BACKREF |
              COMPRESS_ZSTD |
              BIG_METADATA |
              EXTENDED_IREF |
              SKINNY_METADATA )
cache_generation    20919
uuid_tree_generation    20919
dev_item.uuid       f46af693-4975-4df6-af1f-cff7d255800a
dev_item.fsid       1b8c28ca-bf77-46ce-b793-f56a03691c96 [DON'T MATCH]
dev_item.type       0
dev_item.total_bytes    2000398934016
dev_item.bytes_used 1334694641664
dev_item.io_align   4096
dev_item.io_width   4096
dev_item.sector_size    4096
dev_item.devid      2
dev_item.dev_group  0
dev_item.seek_speed 0
dev_item.bandwidth  0
dev_item.generation 0
```

`smartctl -x /dev/sdc` gives

```
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate FireCuda 3.5
Device Model:     ST2000DX002-2DV164
Serial Number:    Z4ZAV9KW
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0b08d7a85
Firmware Version: CC41
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Oct 29 18:12:58 2023 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM level is:     254 (maximum performance)
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, NOT FROZEN [SEC1]
Wt Cache Reorder: Unavailable

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 222) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1081) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   113   099   006    -    56051616
  3 Spin_Up_Time            PO----   098   095   000    -    0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   100   100   020    -    738
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR--   069   060   030    -    8245767
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   089   089   000    -    9654
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   097    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   098   098   020    -    2516
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
184 End-to-End_Error        -O--CK   100   100   099    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1
189 High_Fly_Writes         -O-RCK   098   098   000    -    2
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O---K   072   047   045    -    28 (Min/Max 28/28)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    111
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1683
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   028   053   000    -    28 (0 16 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----C-   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   200   200   000    -    0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       ------   100   253   000    -    10457h+48m+41.266s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      ------   100   253   000    -    20715733063
242 Total_LBAs_Read         ------   100   253   000    -    92642733848
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      5  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x21       GPL     R/O      1  Write stream error log
0x22       GPL     R/O      1  Read stream error log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS      20  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL     VS    3900  Device vendor specific log
0xa8       GPL,SL  VS     129  Device vendor specific log
0xa9       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xab       GPL     VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xb0       GPL     VS    4580  Device vendor specific log
0xbe-0xbf  GPL     VS   65535  Device vendor specific log
0xc0       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc1       GPL,SL  VS      10  Device vendor specific log
0xc4       GPL,SL  VS       5  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (5 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       522 (0x020a)
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    25 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     25/25 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     22/53 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0

SCT Data Table command not supported

SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 2) ==
0x01  0x008  4            2516  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4            9654  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6     20575578727  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6        50053685  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6     11043027816  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6        44889966  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x01  0x038  6               -  ---  Date and Time TimeStamp
0x03  =====  =               =  ===  == Rotating Media Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x03  0x008  4            9118  ---  Spindle Motor Power-on Hours
0x03  0x010  4            9093  ---  Head Flying Hours
0x03  0x018  4            1683  ---  Head Load Events
0x03  0x020  4               0  ---  Number of Reallocated Logical Sectors
0x03  0x028  4               0  ---  Read Recovery Attempts
0x03  0x030  4               0  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4               1  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

Pending Defects log (GP Log 0x0c) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x000a  2            2  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
```

seems it still stuck somewhere in changing UUID process, how can I fix it if anybody can help, I have already spent hours in finding any solution before posting here

Comment: "and it failed" – How? What was the error message? `man btrfstune` states "`-u` Change fsid to a randomly generated UUID or continue previous fsid change operation in case it was interrupted". Have you tried to use `-u` again to continue? And there is `-U`. Have you tried to use `-U` to change to (possibly yet another) UUID?

Comment: running `btrfstune` again gives

`ERROR: dev_item UUID does not match fsid: 1b8c28ca-bf77-46ce-b793-f56a03691c96 != 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ERROR: superblock checksum matches but it has invalid members
ERROR: cannot scan /dev/sdc: Input/output error
WARNING: ignored: dev_item fsid mismatch: 1b8c28ca-bf77-46ce-b793-f56a03691c96 != 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
parent transid verify failed on 924204646400 wanted 20919 found 21414
Ignoring transid failure
leaf parent key incorrect 924204646400
ERROR: could not setup extent tree
ERROR: open ctree failed`